# Is there a way to identify the index of one button among a list of many buttons in the DOM when it is clicked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, event-listener, traversal

I need the function to alert the index of the clicked button

```
var openformbtn=document.querySelectorAll('.show-form');
var formcontainer=document.querySelectorAll('.form-container');
var btnarray = Array.from(openform);
openformbtn.addEventListener('click', displayform);
function displayform(e){
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display='flex';
    var i = btnarray.index(this);
    i.style.display='flex';
}
```

Comment: `var i = btnarray.index(this);` isn't valid, unless you modified the `Array` prototype. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click, it passes a click event to the function, such as:

```js
// We are selecting all the buttons
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");

// we are looping throught the selected buttons.
btns.forEach(btn => {
  // we are adding a click event to the buttons.
  // the (e) stands for event
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // e stands for event

    // To get the clicked element you use e.target


    // document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList
    // To use indexOf we need to make it an array.
    // That is what Array.from() is for.
    const index = Array.from(btns).indexOf(e.target);

    // Now we call a alert using the index
    alert(index);
  });
});
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to do it,

### `id` in HTML

Give a unique `id` to each button, when the button is clicked, get the `id` from the event object `e`.

### `id` passed in JS

When adding an event listener to the button, wrap the listener in an anonymous function and pass the `id` as a parameter, e.g.

```
openformbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  displayform(id)
 });
```

Comment: Where is `id` defined? This breaks the context of `this` in `displayForm()`. Also can't add listener directly to collection returned by `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: You can get the `id` from UUID function or the index of the array when you iterate.